# are endomorphisms "small" compared to the full transformations?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, sequences-and-series, semigroups-and-monoids

$\DeclareMathOperator\End{End}$Let $T_n$ be the full transformation semigroup/monoid of $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$. Let $\End(T_n)$ be the set of [endomorphisms][1] of $T_n$. Then, $\# T_n=n^n$ and
$$\# \End(T_n)=n!\left[1+\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{m-1}2\rfloor}\sum_{r=1}^{m-2k}\frac{m^{n-m}r^{m-k-r}}{2^k(n-m)!(m-2k-r)!k!r!}\right].$$

> **Question.** (a) Is this limit true?
> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\# \End(T_n)}{\# T_n}=0.$$
> Clearly, the automorphism group of $T_n$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{G}_n$, the symmetric group on $[n]$.

> (b) If part (a) holds, then it is reasonable to ask how does $\End(T_n)$ embed (in some sense, say injects) in $T_n$?
> [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism

Comment: "Let $T_n$ be the **monoid/semigroup** of self-maps of $[n]$". Just to make clear you mean endomorphisms of $T_n$ as a semigroup (still there is an ambiguity on whether you require endomorphisms to map identity to itself).

Comment: Do you require $1\mapsto 1$? when not required, it's not true for endomorphisms of arbitrary monoids.

Comment: I'm still a little confused here - do you mean the endomorphisms _of_ $T_n$, or the endomorphisms _within_ $T_n$? Your question makes it seem like the latter (you ask about the 'ratio' of endomorphisms to all transformations) but you haven't imposed any structure on $[n]$ that you're morphing. Otherwise, perhaps it's the hour but I'm just not seeing how you have $End(T_n)\subseteq T_n$ in the first place.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: No, you're not mistaken. I fixed the title.

Comment: @YCor: For example, $\# End(T_2)=7, \# End(T_3)=40$.

Comment: I'm prepared to be surprised, but I would naively expect it to be exactly the opposite, that $\#End(T_n)/\#T_n\to\infty$.

Comment: It's funny you said that, I'd be amusing with the $\infty$.

Comment: This is a question of Schein and TECLEZGHI who computed the endomorpism monoid http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1998-126-09/S0002-9939-98-04764-9/S0002-9939-98-04764-9.pdf

Comment: This count is not requiring the identity to be preserved.

Comment: The fact that $S_n$ is the automorphism group is trivial because automorphisms preserve constant maps. Schein et al give a description that would not seem to give an embedding.

Comment: The paper gives the values for small n and the sequence appears to go to zero.

Comment: I think I have no idea what you're asking. Your answer to my comment seems to suggest you also have no idea what I'm asking. I understood the first interpretation in Steven's comment, and don't get what the second interpretation is. Since some other people seems to have understood the question, they might clarify the question in more universal mathematical language?

Comment: @YCor, the second interpretation makes no sense. Every automorphism of $T_n$ is inner. This must have led the OP to speculate that the endomorphism monoid would also embed in the full transformation semigroup, but that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg: The question by Schein and Teclezghi is about monotonic convergence, not just convergence. Using analytic estimates monotonicty can often only be shown for large $n$, and dealing with the smaller values can be a serious pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the exponential series, we have $\frac{r^k}{k!}\leq e^r$. Hence we have
$$
\frac{r^{m-k-r}}{(m-2k-r)!r!k!} = \frac{1}{r!}\frac{r^k}{k!}\frac{r^{m-2k-r}}{(m-2k-r)!} \leq\frac{e^{2r}}{r!}=\mathcal{O}(1).
$$
From this we obtain
$$
\#End(T_n)\leq Cn! n^3\max_m\frac{m^{n-m}}{(n-m)!} \leq Cn! n^3\max_m\frac{m^{n-m}}{(n-m)!}.
$$
Put $m=\alpha n$. Then
$$
\frac{m^{n-m}}{(n-m)!}\leq \left(\frac{e\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)^{(1-\alpha)n}.
$$
The maximum of $\left(\frac{e\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)^{(1-\alpha)}$ is  about $1.763$, thus for large $n$ we have $\#End(T_n)\leq 1.77^n n!$, which is a lot smaller than $n^n\sim \frac{e^n n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$.

Comment: I noticed that when computing the maximum in the second to last line I left out the factor $e$, which lead to the value 1.33, which is too small. The new value should be correct ,and is still small enough. Note that the upper bound $e^{(1-c)n}$ for some $c>0$ follows from the bound $r^k/k!\leq e^r$ again.